# Is there a map or tool for generating strange unicode character strings?

Tags: unicode

After seeing the famous reply about parsing HTML with regex:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

I've tried to figure out how to do this craziness. Is there a tool that assists with finding these strange characters? How was this done?

Months later, I found this useful as well: http://www.marlborotech.com/Zalgo.html

Comment: For starters, collect all Combining Characters.

Comment: My God, what a link. 4000 upvotes on that answer! I am favoriting that - thank you!